# Missed mash temp

Tags: all-grain, mash-tun

So my mash temp, by the recipe, was 149 F. I missed it by a few degrees, at 144 F. Can I just let it sit longer, or would I have to find a way to increase the temp? This was in a Rubbermaid cooler MLT, so the only way to increase the temp would be to add more, hotter water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do either.

If you leave it at 144, you should definitely let it sit longer. Even a difference of 5 degrees F. can make a significant impact on how long it takes starch to break down (it could take twice as long, or more). It will definitely still convert at 144, and will give you a more fermentable wort (and the resulting beer will be drier). Look for clear wort vs. cloudy wort as a good indication of starch conversion. Or, ideally, [test a sample with iodine](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Iodine_test) to confirm starch breakdown.

I worry getting much below 145 though because then you're pushing the limits on dipping below the [gelatinization point of barley starches](http://homebrewtechniques.com/mashing/starch-gelatinisation-home-brewers-guide/). If the starches don't gelatinize, the enzymes can't reach them and then you have real problems.

If you choose to adjust the heat, adding boiling water to a mash is perfectly acceptable, in fact I'd guess we've all done it at some point. This would get you within spec for the recipe and also speed up conversion.

Comment: I ended up adding boiling water and letting it sit an extra 20 minutes. In the end, I got a gravity of 1.051, just shy of the recipe 1.057, so I think it all worked out fine

Answer (score 1):

144 is at the low end of the saccharification range, so you've still got conversion. You might have a little less dextrin, and a little more fermentables than the recipe intended, but if you're using US/CA/AU 2 row, you've probably have so much enzyme in there that 144 or 149 will give same result.